# Как лучше всего организовать обработчики, для быстрого доступа по их ID?

Tags: node.js

В общем, программа работает с сокетами и получает сообщения от сервера, каждое из которого состоит из числа (0-255) и массива байт. Каждый пакет уже отделен от остальных и ждет своей обработки.

Для каждого ID пакета нужно реализовать свой обработчик, но тогда возникает вопрос в том, как лучше всего структурировать обработчики, чтобы быстро получать к ним доступ, зная требуемый ID.

Также стоит учесть, что для некоторых пакетов не будут определены обработчики, поэтому нужно указать для них стандартный обработчик, который будет выводить сообщение о том, что обработчика для пакета с таким ID нет.

Так как это **JS**, то на ум сразу приходят такие способы как **массивы функций**, **объекты** и череда **switch/case**.

Какой метод мог бы стать наилучшим? Возможно есть более эффективные способы?

Comment: Объект с ключами из ID и значением функции обработчика. Такой объект обернуть в функцию, которая бы тригерила на undefined(если нет обработчика) и возвращала дефолтный

Comment: Хотя и без функции обертки можно обойтись. Массив немного костыльно будет выглядеть, т.к. если вдруг id станут строками, то... switch будет постоянно чекать все значения, пока нужного не найдет. Еще можно в сторону Map посмотреть конечно, но объекта с ключами более чем достаточно(на мой взгляд), если нет задачи динамически добавлять обработчики новым id

Comment: Хм... Думаю ID никогда не перестанет быть целым положительным 8-битным числом.

Comment: Перестанет когда вы его через Кафку прогонять начнёте))

Comment: На сокетах? JS? Возможно это важно, но кроме сокетов, скрипт ничего стороннего больше не использует) Парсится все ручками - моей частью скрипта... Так что ID точно всегда будет числом.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacIAlgA7AE2QFMoBhVdBAbwCgEWEBzKc8iACgEoGzVsNgB7ImFEUAdMlFseAA3zlkcgIQIAkgHIAtggAk9CAAsAlmGliJ0AK7xRUaUWB7yAX0V8A3EOEsnBB2UEQIZpZ+wh6MMYwoaBgAIuQAZsB2yATEZJQ0iQjkAB4Q5KQY2JAw8ISkFNS0GPRxCXSYtbkNBcWl5Vg41dl1eY0MLeKQCJxsltAAnggAvAhE5ADuCACywAAOPADa-gj7AIwANFgd9fnoALpnjLe+jIypdkTw5uIIVyOJAGJ4JxzHjmEgALhWdj0IEoAiYwgoiEcUCWU3IMyqc2kbG4oJIz2E5lSCB46hR8KOIgmUnI0jWwFCSgAcqJEKlRO9EKYcvUkBN7CiEBzUWDFsYwV5CQEWELlil0pkhp0bmAoqwYsIgiEwqsNij+H5xhJabJ5Dxfl10ICUSCTnwcZw8XxnjZJDI5ApLaqbRBgTwAEwOjhcXgunxAA